# Oozie Job log unable to view println statements

Tags: java, oozie, oozie-workflow

I have a few `System.out.println()` statements in my Java code that I am trying to view in the job scheduled using Oozie. I'm unable to find those `println()` statements despite the Job status showing as `SUCCESSFUL`.

My `workflow.xml` looks like:

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.5' name='CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark'>

    <start to='spark-node' />

    <action name='spark-node'>
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>${master}</master>
            <name>HDFS-Test</name>
            <class>Test</class>
            <jar>${nameNode}/user/clsadmin/HDFS-Test/HDFS-Test.jar</jar>
            <configuration> 
                <property> 
                    <name>mapreduce.cluster.acls.enabled</name> 
                    <value>true</value> 
                </property> 
                <property> 
                    <name>mapreduce.job.acl-view-job</name> 
                    <value>*</value> 
                </property> 
            </configuration>
        </spark>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Workflow failed, error message:
            ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}
        </message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

`jobTracker`, `nameNode` and `master` are all defined in my `job.properties`.

Can someone help me with getting the `println` statements to be viewed inside the job log in Oozie web console?

EDIT 1:

Here's the Job Log after you posted that comment. Also updated the above `workflow.xml`:

```
2020-01-21 10:22:55,000  INFO JPAService:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No results found
2020-01-21 10:22:55,036  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2020-01-21 10:22:55,052  INFO StartActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Starting action
2020-01-21 10:22:55,075  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2020-01-21 10:22:55,076  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2020-01-21 10:22:55,098  INFO StartActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Action ended with external status [OK]
2020-01-21 10:22:55,128  INFO JPAService:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] No results found
2020-01-21 10:22:55,145  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@:start:
2020-01-21 10:22:55,145  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W
2020-01-21 10:22:55,182  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Start action [0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2020-01-21 10:22:55,188  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Starting action. Getting Action File System
2020-01-21 10:22:55,212  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Trying to load ShareLib exclude pattern for action.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,214  INFO ShareLibExcluder:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] The following sharelib exclude pattern will be used: oozie/jackson.*
2020-01-21 10:22:55,473  INFO ShareLibExcluder:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Mark file for excluding from distributed cache: /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/jackson-core-2.9.5.jar
2020-01-21 10:22:55,474  INFO ShareLibExcluder:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Mark file for excluding from distributed cache: /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
2020-01-21 10:22:55,474  INFO ShareLibExcluder:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Mark file for excluding from distributed cache: /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
2020-01-21 10:22:55,483  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,484  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.2.7.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.2.7.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,484  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] azure-keyvault-core-1.0.0.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/azure-keyvault-core-1.0.0.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,484  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] azure-storage-7.0.0.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/azure-storage-7.0.0.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,484  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,485  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] hadoop-azure-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/hadoop-azure-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,485  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] hadoop-azure-datalake-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/hadoop-azure-datalake-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,485  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] jetty-util-9.3.24.v20180605.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/jetty-util-9.3.24.v20180605.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,485  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] jetty-util-ajax-9.3.24.v20180605.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/jetty-util-ajax-9.3.24.v20180605.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,485  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] wildfly-openssl-1.0.4.Final.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/wildfly-openssl-1.0.4.Final.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,485  INFO DependencyDeduplicator:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] mapreduce.job.cache.files dependencies are unified by their filename or symlink name.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,488  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Added into spark action configuration mapred.child.env=SPARK_HOME=.,HDP_VERSION=3.1.0.0-78
2020-01-21 10:22:55,489  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Trying to load ShareLib exclude pattern for action.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,490  INFO ShareLibExcluder:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] The following sharelib exclude pattern will be used: oozie/jackson.*
2020-01-21 10:22:55,748  INFO ShareLibExcluder:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Mark file for excluding from distributed cache: /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/jackson-core-2.9.5.jar
2020-01-21 10:22:55,748  INFO ShareLibExcluder:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Mark file for excluding from distributed cache: /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
2020-01-21 10:22:55,748  INFO ShareLibExcluder:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Mark file for excluding from distributed cache: /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
2020-01-21 10:22:55,798  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,799  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.2.7.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.2.7.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,799  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] azure-keyvault-core-1.0.0.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/azure-keyvault-core-1.0.0.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,799  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] azure-storage-7.0.0.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/azure-storage-7.0.0.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,799  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/hadoop-aws-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,799  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] hadoop-azure-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/hadoop-azure-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,799  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] hadoop-azure-datalake-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/hadoop-azure-datalake-3.1.1.3.1.0.0-78.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,799  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] jetty-util-9.3.24.v20180605.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/jetty-util-9.3.24.v20180605.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,799  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] jetty-util-ajax-9.3.24.v20180605.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/jetty-util-ajax-9.3.24.v20180605.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,799  WARN DependencyDeduplicator:523 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] wildfly-openssl-1.0.4.Final.jar[hdfs://chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20190813213920/oozie/wildfly-openssl-1.0.4.Final.jar] is already defined in mapreduce.job.cache.files. Skipping.
2020-01-21 10:22:55,799  INFO DependencyDeduplicator:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] mapreduce.job.cache.files dependencies are unified by their filename or symlink name.
2020-01-21 10:22:57,466  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Trying to get job [job_1575974364931_0384], attempt [1]
2020-01-21 10:22:57,488  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] checking action, hadoop job ID [job_1575974364931_0384] status [RUNNING]
2020-01-21 10:22:57,492  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] [***0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node***]Action status=RUNNING
2020-01-21 10:22:57,492  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] [***0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node***]Action updated in DB!
2020-01-21 10:22:57,498  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node
2020-01-21 10:23:31,755  INFO CallbackServlet:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] callback for action [0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node]
2020-01-21 10:23:31,916  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Trying to get job [job_1575974364931_0384], attempt [1]
2020-01-21 10:23:32,165  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] action completed, external ID [job_1575974364931_0384]
2020-01-21 10:23:32,216  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] Action ended with external status [SUCCEEDED]
2020-01-21 10:23:32,261  INFO JPAService:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] No results found
2020-01-21 10:23:32,281  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@end] Start action [0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@end] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2020-01-21 10:23:32,289  INFO EndActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@end] Starting action
2020-01-21 10:23:32,299  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@end] [***0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@end***]Action status=DONE
2020-01-21 10:23:32,299  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@end] [***0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@end***]Action updated in DB!
2020-01-21 10:23:32,320  INFO EndActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[clsadmin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[CMDW-Security-User-Management-Spark] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@end] Action ended with external status [OK]
2020-01-21 10:23:32,377  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@end] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@end
2020-01-21 10:23:32,378  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W
2020-01-21 10:23:32,378  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[chs-gqc-379-mn002.us-south.ae.appdomain.cloud] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node
```

[image: Job Log]

Comment: Is it possible to show oozie log info what is being printed for this action? Also are you running in yarn-cluster mode or yarn-client mode? Just wanted to understand if it is acl permission issues or something else. Try to run in local mode from oozie and you should see the print statements.

Comment: I'm running in local mode and no println statements are visible there..

Comment: Can you tell what is being displayed in the default section under logs of spark action. In-case if you are facing permission issues while seeing logs have the below comment properties declared in the xml within global tag as shown in the reference.

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a19_Global_Configurations

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml

Note: For now give * in view acl property but you can change accordingly as per need.

Comment: <global> <job-tracker>${job-tracker}</job-tracker> <name-node>${name-node}</name-node> <job-xml>job1.xml</job-xml> <configuration> <property> <name>mapreduce.cluster.acls.enabled</name> <value>true</value> </property> <property> <name>mapreduce.job.acl-view-job</name> <value>*</value> </property> </configuration> </global>

If it was java or shell action we could have used <capture-output/>

Comment: Please check Edit 1

Comment: The log provided seems to be oozie launcher job log. The log i referred to is spark action specific log from hue-->workflows-->(select)job-->tasks-->log(of spark action)-->default. In case if you are not using hue try to check the spark action specific log from oozie web cosole.

Comment: I dont use Hue (and have no option to do so either). I can only use Oozie web console and/or run Oozie commands from terminal. How to check spark action log from Oozie?

Comment: oozie job -oozie ${oozie_url} -info 0000028-200103135925853-oozie-oozi-W@spark-node

From above output, go to 'Console URL' link provided using browser.

Choose successful maps number-->Mapper attempts will be displayed-->Click logs-->Different "Log Type:" will be displayed in this page. Under "Log Type: stdout" click for full log and you should find the println outputs.